# Do sporadic fields exist?

Tags: finite-fields

If we think of fields as groups that also have addition as well as multiplication. Then in the classification of simple groups there are a set of sporadic groups. Are there also such a thing as sporadic fields?

Or if not, are there at least some kind of exceptional fields that have unusual and unique structure? I guess, the complex and quaternions are fairly "unique".

Comment: Re your last sentence, I'd say $\Bbb R$ is "more unique" than $\Bbb C$

Comment: [LMFDB](http://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/) lists some with weird properties

Comment: Every field contains either $\mathbb{Q}$, or $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ ($p$ prime) as a base field. I don't know if that helps answer your question, I'm not sure what would make a field "exceptional" in the context of this question.

Comment: Yeah perhaps fields are too restrictive to be interesting. Maybe I was thinking of algebras in general.

Comment: The quaternions aren't even a field.

Comment: @Kenny you're right.